# WordPress how do I add caption styles in the editor

Tags: css, wordpress, editor

In the current version of WordPress (4.6.1) using the code inspector reveals that the inline style for the image captions is:

`<dd class="wp-caption-dd">Photo Caption Text</dd>`

However, using ".wp-caption-dd" in editor-style.css has no affect - even with !important.  How can I affect the class in the editor to create the same look in the editor that is live?

Please note:  I am only talking about the editor ".wp-caption-text" is the correct class for live coding of the caption.

Charles

Comment: When you look at the code inspector, you should see what file the current style is written in. It most likely has an important! already. If it does, you can either edit in the original file, or make your new css more specific by adding parents. For example: "body .wp-caption-dd" would be more specific than just ".wp-caption-dd".

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome and Inspector I saw the `.wp-caption-dd`, and just putting this in your styles should do.

It should probably be more restrictive (inside the dd specifically), but this should get you started.

```
/* photo caption inside the Visual Editor */
.wp-caption-dd
{
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Trebuchet,"Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,Geneva,Helv;
}
```